# How can I set the dialect in SQL::Parser?

Tags: sql, perl

Why do I get two times "ANSI" and not the first time "ANSI" and the second time "AnyData"?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.010;
use SQL::Parser;                                 


my $parser = SQL::Parser->new();


my @dialects = $parser->list( 'dialects' );
say "available dialects : @dialects"; # AnyData CSV ANSI


my $dialect = $parser->dialect;
say "Current dialect: $dialect"; # ANSI


my $dialect_name = 'AnyData';
$parser->dialect( $dialect_name ); # load a dialect configuration file
$dialect = $parser->dialect; # get the name of the current dialect
say "Current dialect: $dialect"; # ANSI
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a (documentation?) bug in SQL::Parser, AFAICT `new()` is calling `dialect()`, which ensures that the dialect is only set once, preventing you from re-setting it later.
This change was apparently done in version 1.003

Answer (score 3):

I get the same result, but it does seem to work if you specify the dialect in the constructor:

```
my $parser = SQL::Parser->new('AnyData', {RaiseError=>1});
say "Current dialect: " . $parser->dialect; # AnyData
```